# Flutter - Semantics - Explanation

Tags: flutter, semantics

Could anyone give me, a clear explanation (or links) on the notion of Semantics (what is it actually, when to use, update...) in the context of Flutter?

I googled a lot but have not found any good explanation so far.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html "A widget that annotates the widget tree with a description of the meaning of the widgets. Used by accessibility tools, search engines, and other semantic analysis software to determine the meaning of the application."

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer.  Thanks Günter but this does not explain other notions linked to Semantics such as, e.g., in a RenderBox, the overridable method "describeSemanticsConfiguration" (class SemanticsConfiguration)...

Comment: It allows to add semantics to a renderbox which is what widgets are based on. I didn't deep dive into that topic myself yet.

Answer (score 7):

Didier I want to thank you for detailed study & post on your blog, you almost answered your own question, so I wanted to post it here for completeness, in case anyone else is seeking answers on Semantics - it's a great introduction:

https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/07/semantics/

"If you want to debug the Semantics of your application, you may set the `showSemanticsDebugger` property of your `MaterialApp` to `true`. This will force Flutter to generate an overlay to visualize the Semantics tree."

Answer (score 5):

The Flutter SDK doesn’t provide a fine-grained widget for controlling just accessibility. Instead, it contains a class called [Semantics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html), with its description:

> A widget that annotates the widget tree with a description of the meaning of the widgets.

As you can see, the widget doesn’t really care about the specific technology or feature but rather describes general information about the widgets it wraps. That said, most of the features are tailored for the two screen readers.

When you check its [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics/Semantics.html), you can get a sense of how many potential attributes it can take (and features it can support). Most of them end up in the [SemanticsProperties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/semantics/SemanticsProperties-class.html) class.

**Label, value & hint**

One of the common use cases for the Semantics widget is to add a description to your widgets. In Semantics, we have (among others) three useful String parameters for that:

label, which is a brief description of the widget,
hint, which is an explanation of the action that will occur when the widget is interacted with,
and value, which provides a textual description of the widget’s state.
Naturally, you might not need all of them, but in some cases, all of them fit. Let’s see one case where they do:

```
Semantics(
  label: 'Counter button',
  hint: 'Press to increase',
  value: '$_counter',
  onTap: () { setState(() { _counter++; }); }
  child: Text(
    '$_counter',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
  ),
);
```

For the following text (which in fact is also a button, since we specify onTap handler), a user of a screen reader will – assuming that the _counter variable stores zero, hear Counter button, zero, press to increase.

**onCut, onCopy & onPaste**

A useful bunch of properties that can help when interacting with text fields: onCut, onCopy, and onPaste are callbacks that get executed when user executed matching actions on text fields. You can use them to enhance the user experience by providing visual or audible feedback when user manipulates text.

```
Semantics(
  onCopy: () { debugPrint('Hey, where are you taking that?'); },
  onCut: () { debugPrint('Give it back!'); },
  onPaste: () { debugPrint('All right, do not do that again though.'); },
  child: TextField(
    controller: _textEditingController,
    autocorrect: false,
  ),
);
```

Comment: This provide a very good explanation and usage of the semantics widget, +1